# Eclipse Luna No Network Connection

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

I just downloaded the 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' and went to install some updates, however Eclipse does not seem to have any network access. Upon selecting 'Check for Updates' it immediately fails with this error

```
Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/content.xml
download.eclipse.org
Unknown Host: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml
dl-ssl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/luna/content.xml
download.eclipse.org
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/content.xml
download.eclipse.org
Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml
download.eclipse.org
```

The error log is a plethora of failed connections and Provisioning exceptions. I can post the log if requested.

The internal web browser can not access any website either.

Under the network connnections section in the preferences window, I have tried all three options for the Active Provider to no avail.

I am not using a proxy and I have no other network issues. The only similar problems I have found via google have been issues related to proxies.

I am running 64 bit Windows 7.

Does anybody have any idea what the issue might be? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your Windows Firewall allowing the java.exe/javaw.exe, used to launch Eclipse, to open outgoing connections?

Comment: Windows Firewall is allowing Java(TM) Platform SE binary and javaw.exe through. I also disabled the firewall entirely and still had no luck.

Comment: That's a lot of what looks like DNS failures. What is this Active Provider you mention?

Comment: @nitind Under preferences->general->Network Connections there is a dropdown for "Active Provider". The options are native,direct and manual. Googling had suggested that changing this may have been a solution, however in my case it was not.